# Calculating input splits in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, input-split

A file is stored in HDFS of size **260 MB** whereas the HDFS default block size is **64 MB**. Upon performing a map-reduce job against this file, I found the number of input splits it creates is only **4**. how did it calculated.? where is the rest **4 MB**.? Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Input split is NOT always a block size. Input split is a logical representation of data. Your input split could have been 63mb, 67mb, 65mb, 65mb(or possibly other sizes based on logical records' sizes) ... see examples in below links...

[Hadoop input split size vs block size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727468/hadoop-input-split-size-vs-block-size)

[Another example - see section 3.3...](https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/hadoop-inputsplit-vs-blocks/)

Comment: Suppose the logical records size in just few KB. let's say each line/record in the file is of 1 KB, then how many input splits it will generate.?

Comment: 64000 recs will form a one input split of 64mb.

Comment: correct,! but based on the data given in the question, how many input splits will generate when we have each line/record is of 1 KB.? will it be 4 or 5 splits.?

Comment: if all 260MB are all 1 kb that is 260000kb data, 260000/64000=4.06 input splits, but knowing records does not get split between two input splits, seeing ~ 4 input splits in log is expected