# Is the Hadoop Split size the same?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

**A hadoop input splits are same size**, and I knew it could be customized from the developer.

[image]

In the attached figure, **input split size is not same**. Each input split shape is different. I'm confused about the fact that the input sizes were not the same.

The Hadoop definitive guide also mentioned that the input split size is the same.

Does the system make the input size random by the specified size?

Comment: The language here is somewhat unclear - can you edit to clarify your meaning?

Comment: Sorry, I',m not used to English. In the figure, hadoop input split size is not same. Input split shape is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop input split size vs block size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727468/hadoop-input-split-size-vs-block-size)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.