# Spark RDD partitions while reading CSV from AWS S3

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, rdd

I am unable to figure out how spark is deciding on number of partitions while reading from AWS S3

**My Case:**

I am using Spark 1.3 (sorry, but not in my hand)

My **S3 contains 100 csv files** each of size ~60-75MB in batches i.e. folder1,folder2,folder3,etc contains 100 CSV files each

I'm getting **partitions 295-300** while reading from this folders

I'm  expecting that default partitions to be 200 always because if spark understands S3 data as a block-based system then it should read either 64MB or 128MB.

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: In general [block size and split size belong to different layers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17727468/10465355). Ideally these would align, in practice it rarely happens (and in latest versions Spark [doesn't even respect Hadoop split configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38249624/10465355)). So the numbers don't look that alarming.

Comment: can you please explain how this number i.e 300 partitions came ?
Please